# Use Swiper with hexo themes: height becomes 0

Tags: html, css, swiper.js

- Swiper Version: 4.0.0.
- Platform/Target and Browser Versions: Ubuntu 17, Chrome
- Generator: Hexo 3.0 + Hexo-theme-next

#### What you did

I am trying to put Swiper in my header area on my index page. What I did is put the demo file into one swiperheader.swig file. Remove the  tags, and used CDNS links.

Full sample [code](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/220-effect-fade.html)

HTML snippet

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="{{ page.lang || page.language || config.language }}">

  {% set container_class = "container " %}
  {% if theme.sidebar.position %}
    {% set container_class = container_class + 'sidebar-position-' + theme.sidebar.position %}
  {% endif %}

  <div class="{{ container_class }} {% block page_class %}{% endblock %}">
    <div class="headband"></div>
    <header id="header" class="header" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
    {% include 'swiperheader.swig' %}                                                                                  
      <div class="header-inner"> {%- include '_partials/header.swig' %} </div>
    </header>
```

The build is fine without error. The style sheet and .js files are included successfully.

#### Expected Behavior

A swiper region on top of my page like [this](http://www.swiper.com.cn/)

#### Actual Behavior

The swiper region EXISTS but the height is 0. If I put text between SAMPLE then the swiper region extends to a narrow band, shown below (top of the page).

[image]

I am not sure what I did wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with hexo but I've had a similar bug with swiper and an image inside the slide. In my case the problem was that the image inside my swiper slide had position absolute. Every element that has position absolute does not have a height and this again results in a swiper slide being too small because swiper calculates the height according to the elements inside it.

Hope I could help.

Comment: thank you for the quick response! That is the answer. For specific I changed the .swiper-container css to absolute position. I will play with it to see if it is responsive now. Btw would you mind sharing your website with the swiper installation so I can reference if I encounter future questions? I haven't found many websites using swiper and I am really new to css/html. thx!

Comment: My website isn't online so I cant share anything. But Swiper has a great API documentation with many examples.http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/

Comment: Thank you! I will refer to it! By the way are you familiar with css hierarchy? Right now I am having some issues about putting Swiper in my theme's header, which already have few components. The Swiper seems to either overlap with existing header or become very narrow again. It is a css problems which I am very unfamiliar with. The full question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673591/swiper-position-relative-to-other-element-in-header). But anyway thank you very much for your help on this one!