# Swiper position relative to other element in header

Tags: html, css, swiper.js

Hi I am implementing Swiper in my header file but I have problems correctly positioning it.

**WHAT I WANT:**
FUll height Swiper on top of navigation menu

**WHAT I HAVE:**
Limited height Swiper
[image]

or full height covering the navigation menu
[image]

From my very limited understanding of css, I think I should have my *header.css* positioned as relative and *element-wise css* positioned as absolute. The problem is that I do not know the exact dimension of pictures going to be shown with Swiper (*positioned as absolute*) so I cann't use *absolute* for other header elements. But I am probably wrong.

I apologize for my limited knowledge and misunderstandings of css/html. Very new learner.

**Template file:**

*limited height siwper*

```
<header id="header" class="header" >
  <div class="header-swiper"> 
        {%- include 'swiperheader.swig' %} 
   </div>
  <div class="header-inner"> 
          {%- include '_partials/header.swig' %} 
   </div>
</header>
```

*full height swiper covering nav-menus*

```
<header id="header" class="header" >
  <div class="header-swiper"> 
        {%- include 'swiperheader.swig' %} 
   </div>
  <div class="header-inner"> 
          {%- include '_partials/header.swig' %} 
   </div>
</header>
```

**CSS structure:**

*Main css:*

```
.header { position: relative; background: $head-bg; height: 100%;}

.header-swiper { height: 100%; }
.header-inner { position: relative; height: 100%; }

@import "site-meta";
@import "site-nav";
@import "menu";
```

*Swiper css:*

```
.swiper-container {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 30%;                                                                                                     
    }
```

**Other header element css:**

*site-meta.css*

```
.site-meta {                                                                                                           
  margin: 0;
  text-align: $site-meta-text-align;

  +mobile() { text-align: center; }
}

.brand {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 40px;
  color: $brand-color;
  background: $brand-bg;
  border-bottom: none;
  &:hover { color: $brand-hover-color; }
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
  line-height: 36px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.site-title {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
```

*site-nav.css:*

```
.site-nav-toggle {                                                                                                     
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  +mobile() {
    display: block;
  }

  button {
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
  }
}

.site-nav {
  +mobile() {
    display: none;
    margin: 0 -10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    clear: both;
    border-top: 1px solid $gray-lighter;
  }
```

*menu.css:*

```
.menu {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu .menu-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  list-style: none;

  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
```

**full swiperheader.swig code**

```html
  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.0/css/swiper.min.css">

  <!-- Demo styles -->
  <style>
    html, body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color:#000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper-container {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
   position: relative;
      height:auto;
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
    }
    .swiper-slide.background-image {
   position: relative;
    }
  </style>

  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nightlife/1)">WCO</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nightlife/2)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nightlife/3)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nightlife/4)"></div>
      <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/nightlife/5)"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-white"></div>
    <!-- Add Arrows -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      spaceBetween: 30,
      effect: 'fade',
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont quite get what you're trying to achieve. If you are trying to get a full height swiper slide you need to set the height in your swiper-container class to 100% instead of 50. Of course the swiper slide will then cover your second part of the header. The reason for that is, that you set the height of your header to 100%. Therefore a swiper slide with 100% height will simply cover the whole header.

If you want to have a 100% swiper and the second part of your header underneath this slide just put the

```
<div class="header-inner"> 
      {%- include '_partials/header.swig' %} 
</div>
```

part outside of your `</header>` Tag.

If you want to have a 100% swiper and the second content on Top of your swiper just put the

```
<div class="header-inner"> 
      {%- include '_partials/header.swig' %} 
</div>
```

inside the swiper slides.

If you try to achieve something else please explain me what exactly you need to change.

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you very much for your answer. It is clear and helpful. I want to learn how to arrange different elements in header basically. So from your answer, if <header> is 100%, a 100% <swiper> will take all the space. So I should put <swiper> outside in order to get a stack instead of overlap. However, if I would still want all elements to be part of <header>, just for organization reasons, I should adjust the height of each component so they add up to 100%? Thank you very much!

Comment: You could do that OR you could just remove the "height:100%" from your header. headers dont have a given minimal or maximal height. Your header can be 10 times the screen size if you want to. In your case you set your header to 100% and therefore it cannot be filled with 2 100% elements